# Python exe imports

Tags: python, exe

Need to Export a python project into an `exe` file.

1. I want to share it to people who don't have/use python.
2. The exe export still work on their respective computer?
3. Also, I have Pandas dependency import which requires a `pip install`. still work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`PyInstaller`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/), a package created to build standalone applications:

> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package.
> The user can run the packaged app **without installing a Python
> interpreter or any modules**.

So in this case there won't be problems in using Pandas.